# Need Project size of the projects in the sql db

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query the specific projects and that project size in whole db, I am able to get the output with project names but I want to know the size of that projects in DB.

I have tried the below query and got the output of the projects which I need:

```
qtest=> select name from projects where name like 'MLC%' and issampleproject=false and enddate is null and issampleproject=false;
                     name
----------------------------------------------
MLC Customers
MLC DELIVERY
MLC Delivery - Clone - Copy-Paste Test
MLC (Sydney)
(4 rows)
```

I need the size of the above projects.

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? Is that a column in the table? The amount of space those 4 rows take up on disk?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.